# How to pass a pointer to function which changes the pointer, using CFFI

Tags: python, c, pointers, python-cffi, cffi

I have the following c function into which I want to pass a dummy pointer so that I can retrieve the generated array:

```
int generateFloatArr(float **outputArr){
  float result[4] = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0};
  *outputArr=&result;
  return 4;
}
```

With it, I can do the following in c:

```
  float *output;

  int arrLen = generateFloatArr(&output);
  printf("%f \n",output[0]); //prints "1.000000"
```

With CFFI I am stuck interacting with this function.

I can create a pointer with:

```
p_floatArr=ffi.new("float *")
```

But I'm unsure how to get the address of `p_floatArr` to pass into `lib.generateFloatArr()`.

I tried this instead which the [python-CFFI docs](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#working-with-pointers-structures-and-arrays) seem to suggest doing:

```
p_p_floatArr=ffi.new("float **")
lib.generateFloatArr(p_p_floatArr)
print(p_p_floatArr[0][0])
```

However the float value is incorrect. If I do the analog of the above in c:

```
  float **output;

  generateFloatArr(output);
  printf("%f \n",output[0][0]);
```

This gives a segfault.

How can I properly pass a pointer (to a pointer) to this function?

Comment: `float result[4];   *outputArr=&result; `  returns a pointer to an array on the current stack.

Comment: Can't help with the Python, but try putting a `static` in front of the array definition... Not an 'automatic/local' array that evaporates.

Comment: And that array is released at function exit & is no longer usable. I don't know about CFFI, but this won't work that way.

Comment: Can you pass in a pointer to an existing array to be filled in with values? You have to deal with object lifetime here. A static as @Fe2O3 suggests could work if one single array is acceptable, i.e. every single call would return the same identical object, not independent ones.

Comment: `static` is no the solution.

Comment: @AviBerger I could but preference is to allocate within the function (I return the array size in addition to the pointer so the caller knows the bounds)

Comment: Well, your current C function doesn't allocate an array that remains usable once it returns. To do that, unless the limit of 1 array total for all invocations was acceptable, you'd need to use malloc in the function and you would need another function that you would call exactly once with each returned array to release it when you were done with it.

Comment: You can't return a local variable which **scope** is the local function, meaning that after return local variables doesn't exist anymore. Use instead dynamic memory to allocate the array: `*outputArr=malloc(sizeof(float)*4);`. Remember to check the pointer before to use it because `malloc()` can fail. You can insert the values you want in the new array before to return it. If the array you return is immutable, so can be shared with other functions, is acceptable to return a `static const float result[4]={....};`.

Comment: Thanks re malloc however I receive a segfault before I even get to any function code if I pass in the parameter instantiated as `float **output;`. There seems to be no way in CFFI to instantiate as `float *output;` then pass `&output`.

Comment: Can you create a `float **dpOutput` and a `float *pOutput` as well; set dpOutput = &pOutput; and pass in dpOutput ? And with that I'm off to sleep. Good luck.

Comment: Would all you haters please examine the C code in the first code block of the OP. THIS is the reason for my earlier comment about `static`... SO seems to be a place where poor understanding is always the fault of someone else.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Your reasoning is not clear. Please add an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within `generateFloatArr()`, either:

1. `*outputArr` needs to be allocated with `malloc()` and then filled with values, or
2. result needs to be initialized as `static const float result[4]={...}`

From the python side, it works to do:

```
p_p_floatArr=ffi.new("float **")
lib.generateFloatArr(p_p_floatArr)
print(p_p_floatArr[0][0])
```